# Extending the Rally agile EVM app

Tags: rally

The Rally Agile EVM app is very useful but only estimates and totals the story points for a given release. I would like to extend the app to include defect points in the total.

Has anyone done this before? Could anyone provide an example or source?

[Agile EVM app](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/agile-evm-app)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

LNS,

The code for this app is available at the page you reference above. Here is the exact [link](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/appdefinition/AgileEVM.html). You are welcome to modify the code and use the general documentation for the [App SDK](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/app-sdk) to help. If you have any questions, please create another post here and we will do our best to answer it.

-- Mark

Comment: Mark, thanks for the response. I am not a developer and have not been able to get it to work correctly. I was hoping that some one had already updated the app. Thanks.